# How to use @SuiteClasses when more than 20 or 50 classes to be tested?

Tags: unit-testing, junit

I wanted to know that if I have to test several classes what should be the good strategy for to specify and deal with large number of classes to be tested... it would be tedious and wouldn't be efficient to specify all classes when the count is 50 or more per se.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to find specific suites to help you that are not covered by the standard junit.

Several exist, but in your case, I believe that [cpsuite](https://github.com/takari/takari-cpsuite) is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can organize the test classes by nesting suites, that is, the classes added as `@SuiteClasses` can be suites themselves.